# Visa Requirement for Ecuador - Indian Citizen

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, tourist-visas, ecuador, timatic

Anyone know what the visa requirement is for Indian citizens who want to visit Ecuador?

Most popular answer I find from Google is Visa on Arrival with Indian passport valid for 6 months, but I've also seen others saying prior visa or eVisa needed.

If someone could paste the Timatic requirements, that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://www.passportindex.org/comparebyPassport.php, an e-Visa is required.

This is confirmed by Timatic, which says:

- Visa required
- E-visas can be obtained before departure at https://www.consuladovirtual.gob.ec/web/guest/inicio Passengers must have a printed e-visa confirmation which can be verified at https://evisaecuador.cancilleria.gob.ec:444/

Source: https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b